# Unsubscribe handler on Webclient event on C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webclient

I wanted to implement a method in charge to subscribe my Webclient to handlers and when I want to unsubscribe it seems it is not done correctly.
I have an example :

my function used to subscribe

```
private void SendRequest(Action<object, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs> callback, string url)
{
    if (!wClient.IsBusy)
    {
        wClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(callback);
        wClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url), "POST");        
        [...]
    }
}
```

my handlers

```
private void wClient_request1Completed(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    wClient.UploadStringCompleted -= wClient_request1Completed;
    [...]
}

private void wClient_request2Completed(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    wClient.UploadStringCompleted -= wClient_request2Completed;
    [...]
}
```

and I use these methods like this

```
private WebClient wClient = new WebClient();

SendRequest(wClient_request1Completed, myUrl1);
// wClient_request1Completed(..) is run successfully

[... Request 1 is already completed ...]

SendRequest(wClient_request2Completed, myUrl2);
// wClient_request1Completed(..) and wClient_request2Completed(..) are run
```

Do you have an idea about my problem ?
Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're implicitly creating a new delegate as parameter of your `SendRequest` method. Basically, your current code could be rewritten to:

```
// Done implicitly by the compiler
var handler = new Action<object, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs>(wClient_request1Completed); 

wClient.UploadStringCompleted += handler;

// ...

wClient.UploadStringCompleted -= wClient_request1Completed // (instead of handler)
```

One way to fix it could be to use the payload parameter of the `UploadStringAsync` method to keep a reference to the handler:

```
var handler = new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(callback);
wClient.UploadStringCompleted += handler;
wClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url), "POST", null, handler);
```

Then, in the `UploadStringCompleted` event:

```
private void wClient_request1Completed(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var handler = (UploadStringCompletedEventHandler)e.UserState;

    wClient.UploadStringCompleted -= handler ;
    [...]
}
```

That said, you should consider switching to `HttpClient` and the async/await programming model, as it would make your code way easier to understand.